# How to add x% to a value and INSERT it in a MySQL Table?

Tags: mysql, sql, insert

Hey guys I'd like to know if there is a SQL Query that makes it possible to insert a value after adding x% to it?

For example:

```
INSERT INTO `player_classlevelstats` (`class`, `level`, `basehp`, `basemana`) VALUES (1, 70, 4444, 0);
```

Is my currently query. Is there any possibility to add now the following:

```
INSERT INTO `player_classlevelstats` (`class`, `level`, `basehp`, `basemana`) VALUES (1, 71, 4666, 0);
```

BaseHP '4666' = 4444 + 5% - It would be very usefull and I need it until level is at 255. Thanks!

Comment: Adding 5% is the same as multiplying by 1.05. Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you have a table of all possible levels (going to 255):

```
INSERT INTO `player_classlevelstats` (`class`, `level`, `basehp`, `basemana`)
    select 1, l.level, 4444 * pow(1.05, l.level - 70), 0
    from levels l
    where l.level >= 70 and l.level <= 255;
```

If you don't have a separate table *and* you have examples in the original data from all levels, then you could do:

```
INSERT INTO `player_classlevelstats` (`class`, `level`, `basehp`, `basemana`)
    select 1, l.level, 4444 * pow(1.05, l.level - 70), 0
    from (select distinct level from player_classlevelstats) l
    where l.level >= 70 and l.level <= 255;
```

Comment: I think I forgot to tell you that the value with +5% should be placed in a new row.

The diff would be the following: 

1,70,4444,0,
1,71,4666,0,

so: +0,+1,+5%,+5%

Comment: These queries generate multiple rows, a single row for each new level.

Answer (score 1):

if can you use a stored procedure, try:

```
delimiter //
 CREATE PROCEDURE my_proc()
 BEGIN

   SELECT 4444 INTO @v2;
   SELECT 70 INTO @v1;

   WHILE @v1 <= 255 DO

     INSERT INTO `player_classlevelstats` (`class`, `level`, `basehp`, `basemana`) 
      VALUES (1, @v1, @v2, 0);

     SELECT ROUND(@v2 * 1.05) INTO @v2;
     SET @v1 = @v1 +1;
   END WHILE;
 END;
 //


 call my_proc();
```

Comment: I guess - but it will only insert 1 row, it would be nice if it reads the last entry in 'basehp' and add 5%.

So at 71 it is 7666 and then add again 5% until 255.

Comment: I think I forgot to tell you that the value with +5% should be placed in a new row.

The diff would be the following: 

1,70,4444,0,
1,71,4666,0,

so: +0,+1,+5%,+5%